# how get the req, res objects in the callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I like to get the req, res, next objects outside the middleware function.

sample middleware - sample.js:

```
var app = express();
....
.....
....
var updateUserInput = {
   init:function(){
       get_data_from_db(params, function(){
           // want req, res here.
       })
   }
}

const processUserInput = function(req, res, next){
   updateUserInput.init();
}
module.exports = processUserInput;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to pass those into the init function right away:

```
var updateUserInput = {
   init:function(req,res,next){
       get_data_from_db(params, function(){
           // You will have req and res available here
           // finish processing and call next()
       })
   }
}

const processUserInput = function(req, res, next){
   updateUserInput.init(req,res,next);
}
```

Comment: I have so many functions in the file and I don't want to pass the req, res, next objects around into all of them. Also sometimes few functions have their own params to be passed. there I cannot pass them.

Comment: That's why you have the object pattern.. use init: function(req,res,next){ this.req = req; this.res = res; this.next = next} then use this.req or whatever n the other functions

Comment: Thanks @bitanath. I was just looking for options whether is there a way to get req, res from the app itself instead of passing around. When I use object pattern the callbacks of other objects declared outside updateUserInput will not get the req, res objects.